# ¿Cómo realizar una sola búsqueda consultando diferentes tablas en la BD?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy tratando de crear una forma en la que
mediante la implementación de un buscador me regrese los datos con la palabra introducida en el buscador, el problema es que tengo diferentes tablas de productos y lo que quiero es que al hacer la búsqueda, obtenga todos los productos relacionados con esa palabra independientemente de donde (en que tabla) se encuentre dicho producto.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Tengo 7 diferentes tablas de productos en las cuales quiero realizar la búsqueda.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es posible. Pero tengo curiosidad de saber ¿por qué tienes **varias tablas de productos** y no una sola tabla `productos`? El querer juntarlas en una sola consulta podría ser un indicativo de que debería existir **una sola tabla productos**.

Comment: Muestranos la definicion de la base de datos y que tiene cada tabla. Como dice @A.Cedano, pareceria haber un claro error de diseño en esto.

Comment: porque es más fácil tenerlos divididos porque tienen diferentes campos cada uno

Comment: Dudo de que a la largar esa afirmación de que `es más fácil tenerlos divididos porque tienen diferentes campos cada uno` se pueda sostener.  En cualquier caso y aun que ya tengas la solución a tu problema, recomendaría revisar el diseño de tu base de datos antes de continuar. Que tengas 7 tablas hoy puede que sea manejable, pero si por mal diseño mañana se convierten en 50 o 100 dudo que sea manejable.

Comment: @HeberSolis que seran diferentes campos? porque uno esta en kilos y otro en litros? Te puedo asegurar, que igual no es la forma de hacerlo. Muestra tu definicion de las tablas. Porque por mas que tengas respuestas decentes, ninguna se va a sostener en el tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Si por algún motivo debes tener siete tablas, imagino que será porque definitivamente **no hay otra posibilidad**, ya que mantener tal diseño podría convertirse tarde o temprano en algo difícil o imposible de manejar, mantener, actualizar.

No obstante, si no hay otra alternativa, la consulta se podría obtener uniendo las tablas mediante `UNION`.

Por ejemplo:

```
  SELECT producto_nombre
  FROM (SELECT producto_nombre FROM productos_1
        UNION 
        SELECT producto_nombre FROM productos_2
        ... otras tablas
       ) AS tablas
  WHERE tablas.producto_nombre LIKE '%Café%';
```

Ahora bien, para no complicar más la cosa, *al menos* trata de que el nombre de la columna `producto_nombre` o como se llame, sea el mismo en todas las tablas, o tendrás que repetir también la clásula `WHERE` tantas veces como tablas intervengan.

Aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo con una posibilidad de consulta tal y como has planteando la pregunta, es decir, usando tablas separadas. En el ejemplo he imaginado que las tablas están separadas por el hecho de que en una requieres el país de origen del producto y en otra requieres el fabricante, etc.

Al mismo tiempo, indico otra posibilidad: tener todos los productos en una sola tabla, la cual reúne los datos requeridos en las otras dos tablas mediante un campo id para país y otro para fabricante. Lo mismo se podría hacer con campos como proveedor, tipo de producto, etc.

Podrás apreciar la simplicidad de la consulta en ese modelo. En un modelo con siete o más tablas para algo que debería ser considerado como una *entidad* la más mínima cosa se complica. Imaginemos que haya que ordenar alfabéticamente los resultados... o que haya otros requerimientos más serios como tener que hacer cálculos, etc. O si hay que traer otros datos relacionados con esos productos como el país, la marca, el fabricante...

Bueno, aquí va el código:

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/ELVEM17158)

```
 -- Varias tablas

 CREATE TABLE productos_1 (
          producto_id  SERIAL,
          producto_nombre VARCHAR(100),
          pais_id INT
        );

 INSERT INTO productos_1 (producto_nombre, pais_id) 
            VALUES ('Café',1),('Arroz',2);        



 CREATE TABLE productos_2 (
          producto_id  SERIAL,
          producto_nombre VARCHAR(100),
          fabricante_id INT
        );


 INSERT INTO productos_2 (producto_nombre, fabricante_id) 
            VALUES ('BMW Café',1),('Toyota Yaris',2);  



-- Una tabla
CREATE TABLE productos (
          producto_id  SERIAL,
          producto_nombre VARCHAR(100),
          pais_id INT,
          fabricante_id INT
        );


      INSERT INTO productos (producto_nombre, pais_id, fabricante_id) 
            VALUES ('Café',1,3),('Arroz',2,4),('BMW Café',3,1),('Toyota Yaris',4,2);        



 -- Tablas auxiliares

 CREATE TABLE paises (
          pais_id  SERIAL,
          pais_nombre VARCHAR(50)
        );


 INSERT INTO paises (pais_nombre) 
            VALUES ('Colombia'),('China'),('Alemania'), ('Japón');  


 CREATE TABLE fabricantes (
          fabricante_id  SERIAL,
          fabricante_nombre VARCHAR(50)
        );


 INSERT INTO fabricantes (fabricante_nombre) 
            VALUES ('Colombia Cofee Ltd.'),('China Rices & Co.'),('Deutch Cars'), ('Karritos Jp');  


-- Consulta con varias tablas

 SELECT producto_nombre
 FROM (SELECT producto_nombre FROM productos_1
       UNION 
       SELECT producto_nombre FROM productos_2
      ) AS tablas
  WHERE tablas.producto_nombre LIKE '%Café%';


-- Consulta con una tablaa


 SELECT pr.producto_nombre, pa.pais_nombre, fa.fabricante_nombre 
     FROM productos pr 
     INNER JOIN paises pa      ON pr.pais_id=pa.pais_id
     INNER JOIN fabricantes fa ON pr.fabricante_id=fa.fabricante_id
 WHERE pr.producto_nombre LIKE '%Café%';
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

```
--Consulta con varias tablas

    producto_nombre
1   Café
2   BMW Café

--Consulta con una tabla mostrando más datos de tablas relacionadas

    producto_nombre     pais_nombre    fabricante_nombre
1   Café                Colombia       Deutch Cars
2   BMW Café            Alemania       Colombia Cofee Ltd.
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tienes TABLA1, TABLA2, TABLE3... etc, y dices que TODAS guardan productos, es correcto?, voy a asumir que la columna con el nombre del producto se llama NOMBRE_PRODUCTO y que asi le pusiste a TODAS las 7 tablas.

```
SET @var = 'dulce';
Select NOMBRE_PRODUCTO from TABLA1 where NOMBRE_PRODUCTO like '%'+@var+'%'
UNION
Select NOMBRE_PRODUCTO from TABLA2 where NOMBRE_PRODUCTO like '%'+@var+'%'
UNION
Select NOMBRE_PRODUCTO from TABLA3 where NOMBRE_PRODUCTO like '%'+@var+'%'
UNION
Select NOMBRE_PRODUCTO from TABLA4 where NOMBRE_PRODUCTO like '%'+@var+'%'
--(Y así continuas)
```

@var es una variable, ahi asigna un valor, si estas mando las consultas de php, entonces solo creas una variables y sustituye @var por tu variable en el query que vas a mandar como una cadena completa. otra cosa, como ya dije yo use "NOMBRE_PRODUCTO" para todas las columnas, tu pon el nombre que tienes para cada tabla.

Ya que tengas el query armada pruebalo así en tu mysql / phpmyadmin

Cambia "dulce" por algo que haga mas sentido para ti.

Answer (score 1):

Con el buscador para buscar en 7 tablas veo dos temas a considerar. Por un lado las búsquedas con like generarán full scan sobre las 7 tablas cada vez que se haga una búsqueda. Y la otra es que una vez encontrados los matches vas a necesitar saber de que dabla vinieron y el id dentro de la tabla.

Una posible solución para este escenario sería usar una tabla como índice.

Sería así:

Cuando se agrega un producto a su respectiva tabla se separa en palabras el nombre del producto. Y cada palabra es insertada en la tabla índice junto con un identificador de en que tabla está el producto y su id.

Cuando queres buscar un producto, haces un select sobre la tabla índice por las palabras ingresadas en el criterio donde podes implemetar alternativas de AND y OR si quisieras.

El resultado te dirá que productos cumplen el criterio y en que tabla están.

Para optimizar esta búsqueda, de las palabras a guardar eliminaría preposiciones y artículos, e indexaría la tabla de índice por el campo palabra.